# SQL query - Group by an approximation

Tags: sql, database, request

I have a query: SELECT ID, Name, Distance FROM Station GROUP BY 'Distance approximation'

In my example, Distance is a double and I would like to group all the elements with the same approximate distance together. For example, element_1 with distance 212 will be in the same group as element_2 with distance 240 but not in the same group as 300 (difference is > 50).

Thanks

Comment: Say there are elements at 200, 240, 280.  Would they all be in the same group, since they're less than 50 apart?

Comment: i think you want `order by` only .. am i wrong??

Comment: You could also use a windowing function and order by it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your database, you can group by a function.

So you could do something like (very simple)

```
select round(distance/50) as approximate_distance, count(*)
   from station
   group by round(distance/50)
```

You can add in your own functions based on your requirements.

Comment: it's /50 because in the original query, they were grouping by stations within 50 miles

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to divide the distance by 50 make it an integer and group by that result.

Something like this: (not tested)

```
  SELECT floor(Distance/50) as [group], count(*) as count
  FROM Station 
  GROUP BY floor(Distance/50)
```

The one drawback of this way is that two numbers close to each other could still be in different groups.  For example distance of 249 would be in a different group than 251.

Since any such grouping would require some boundary points, you need to be clear about your requirements -- then an algorithm can be designed.

Comment: you can't `select` non group by columns what you have done !!

Comment: This query would only show a single ID and station, per distance group.

Comment: @pratik - fixed, early morning snafu